# how to call bash function on login as root user

Tags: bash, permissions, arch-linux, sudo, bash-scripting

I'm using Arch (with Xfce) and need to run a bash function when I log in to my OS.
The function that I wrote, needs to be run by root access.

This is the function:

```bsh
my_func() {
   sudo -v
   sudo chown $USER /var/lib/pgadmin
   sudo chown $USER /var/log/pgadmin
   python3 -m venv pgadmin4
   source pgadmin4/bin/activate
   pgadmin4
}
export -f my_func
```

I can easily run `my_func` in the terminal. First, it prompts for a password, and then it works.

For some reason, I have to run the function when I log in.

###### What I did:

I have created a bash script (my_function.sh) and added it to "Session and Startup > Application Autostart". But because that function needs to be run by the root user, it fails

Comment: This is really an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) at best: Why do you need to change ownership like that? Create a group that you are a member of and that can access `/var/lib/pgadmin` and `/var/log/pgadmin`. Then change `/var/lib/pgadmin` and `/var/log/pgadmin` to be group readable and writable, and assign yourself to that group. No need to run `sudo` each time you login which is really a bad idea.

Comment: Might it be a good idea to leave that as an answer, i.e. an example of "how to actually do it"?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a [systemd unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd#Using_units) for this.

Here's a [basic tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/run-shell-script-as-systemd-service/) on the way to do it.

Typically in your case you would want to have

```
[Unit]
Description=PGAdmin

[Service]
ExecStart= #Path of my_function.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```